# Translate book-length text to mp3 audio

Tags: mp3, text-to-speech

I have a 70 chapter book that I need to have read aloud to me. My sight is failing after 45 years. I need book.txt translated to book.mp3.

Comment: You might want to look into DAISY books. https://openlibrary.org/help/faq/accessing You can also install a DAISY reader on Ubuntu by running the following command: `sudo apt install daisy-player` Some books are copyright protected and for these books, you may need to apply for NLS service to obtain a key https://www.loc.gov/nls/enrollment-equipment/apply-for-nls-service/ or you can call 1-800-424-8567 for help. You must be a United States citizen to apply for a key but a key is not always required.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DAISY_Digital_Talking_Book

Answer (score 2):

First, run the following commands to install the dependencies:

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install lame espeak
```

Next, run the following commands to convert the file from text to wave to mp3:

```
espeak -s 155 -a 200 -f book.txt -w book.wav
lame -V2 book.wav book.mp3
```

If you don't want the `wav` file you can delete the file.

The `espeak` command options set the speed of words per minute to `155` and the amplitude to `200`.

Use `espeak --help` for more options.

Comment: Just found this!  Alz, ?...  --{worde than death.}  For the record, I pieced things together and used the info above to create a scipt that works fine.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a dual boot, try using Balabolka .. Or borrow a friend's computer.
The official website (be careful) is http://www.cross-plus-a.com/balabolka.htm

Balabolka ***does work in Wine*** but it is 32bit so follow the instructions.

I think I used this webpage to follow the directions.. 
https://www.reddit.com/r/linux/comments/6z41qb/my_text_to_speech_tts_solution_wine_microsoft/

The content from that page is:

The Solution. It was surprisingly simple. Download the 32bit version of SpeechPlatformRuntime.msi from https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=27225 and MSSpeech_TTS_en-US_ZiraPro.msi from https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=27224 this should work with the other voices as well.

```
$export WINEARCH=win32
$export WINPREFIX=~/.wine32
$winetricks msxml3
$wine msiexec /i SpeechPlatformRuntime.msi
$wine msiexec /i MSSpeech_TTS_en-US_ZiraPro.msi
```

After that you should be able to use any windows tts program that uses Microsoft Speech Platform v11. I use Balabolka's Command Line Utility http://www.cross-plus-a.com/bconsole.htm it's a simple console app and doesn't require any extra dependencies.

Answer (score 0):

There are many online services that let you convert a TXT file to MP3.
for example:
https://onlineconvertfree.com/convert-format/txt-to-mp3/

There are many others.

If you want to be able to do this offline, you can write a simple python sript, see this discussion:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19683282/how-can-i-convert-a-text-file-to-audio-mp3-using-ffmpeg-on-ubuntu-11-04